# WHy am I keep getting an error message or build error message?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS 2010 express but everytime when I open something in Win32 cosole application or any other projects, I keep getting build error. But everytime I start my new project with Empty Project, it always works well...nothing but Empty Project works. BTW, I coded properly and even used sample Win32 console application source codes and it still gives me an error. Is there something wrong with my computer setting?

```
------ Build started: Project: rwtwtwtwtw, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
dfgdfgdf.cpp
LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing what errors you get and for which code.

Comment: it's not the codes that gives me an error..it always stop at build error saying they can't find a file or something like that..

Comment: Yes and it's *still* impossible to say what's wrong. And with that I mean that you need to **edit your question** to include the *complete* and *unedited* error log. And please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg said **edit**, not comment!

Comment: I edited...I included the output build error...I am very new to C++ sorry.

Comment: Check with Task Manager that you don't have *tons* of EXE running (your old projects debugging sessions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for LNK1123, you will find that it is very frequently caused by having VS2010 installed along with another version if Visual studio (googling for strange error codes is a useful technique!). If you have this situation, it appears that upgrading VS2010 to service pack 1 will fix it.